# Extracting Data from Expression<Func<,>>

Tags: c#, expression, func

Im having a little trouble about extracting some data from `Expression<Func<,>>`, and having more trouble explaining what i want.

So i have a rest API and im building a method that could work as WFC.

meaning that i will not be needing to call the rest api by url but. 
Building an interface or some kind of wrapper and from that interface we could extract the rest api controller Name, method and parameters.

Ok let me show you how i have imagine it to work.

> This is my controller interface

```
[Route(url: "api/")]
public interface IYoutubeController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a collection of the searched youtube videos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchString"></param>
    /// <param name="pageSize"></param>
    /// <param name="relatedTo"></param>
    /// <param name="videoSearchType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route]
    YoutubeVideoCollection Search(string searchString, int pageSize = 50, string relatedTo = null, VideoSearchType videoSearchType = VideoSearchType.Videos);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the playlist video contents
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="playListId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route]
    List<YoutubeItem> Playlist(string playlistId);

    /// <summary>
    /// decrypted youtube video
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="videoId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route(httpMethod: HttpMethod.POST)]
    Task<YoutubeVideoInfo> GetVideoAsync(string videoId);
}
```

> This the controller Repository

```
public static class ControllerRepository
{
    public static async Task<P> Execute<P>(Expression<Func<IYoutubeController, P>> func)
    {
        return await HttpHelper.ExecuteAsync(func);
    }
}
```

Now i could simple call my method like this

```
 YoutubeVideoCollection test = await ControllerRepository.Execute(x => x.Search("Eminem"));
```

You can se that there is no method seach exist, its only a method in interface.

And here is a httphelper, in it exist `PostAsync` and `GetAsync` and also `ExecuteAsync`

```
 private static string baseUrl = "http://xxx"
 public static async Task<P> ExecuteAsync<T, P>(Expression<Func<IYoutubeController, P>> func) 
    {
        var url= typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<Route>()?.Url ?? ""; // eg api/
        var controller = typeof(T).Name; // eg IYoutubeContrller, will be renamed to youtube later on
        var method = // get the method from func P which is Search
        var parameters = // the parameter data from func which is Eminem
        var fullUrl= $"{baseUrl}/{url}/{controller}" 
        // and here we do PostAsync<P>(fullUrl, parameters ) Or GetAsync<P>(fullUrl, parameters )
    }
```

In `HttpHelper ExecuteAsync` i want to retrive from my `Func<T, P>` the Method name which is `Search` and the parameter which is `searchString` and also the value of the parameter which is `Eminem`

Could you help me retrive these information from `func` parameter?

This is still an idee, so it may not really work, just let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **very special** case:

```
Execute(x => x.Search("Eminem"));
```

You could do this

```
public static async Task<P> ExecuteAsync<T, P>(Expression<Func<IYoutubeController, P>> func)
{    
    MethodCallExpression callExpression = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    string methodName = callExpression.Method.Name;
    object argument = ((ConstantExpression)callExpression.Arguments).Value;
    // do something
}
```

But of course this will crash if the expression passed to `Execute` is more complicated or uses calls with no arguments or non-constant expression arguments etc.
But in that case, you wouldn't know which information to extract at all.

Comment: But im now having this error when using Expression instead of Func `An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments`, it not accepting the argument Search("Eminem")

Comment: Yes, for an expression you need to provide all arguments to the `Search` call. Didn't see that there are further optional arguments. So you need to change the _call_ to `x.Search("Eminem", 50, null, VideoSearchType.Videos);`